# Ajax callback return 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: 7, ajax, routes

file mymodule.inc :

```
        $items['ajax/channel/%/get-program'] = array(
        'title' => t('get channel program by ID'),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'page callback' => 'get_channel_program',
        'page arguments' => array(2),
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
      );

      return $items;
//channel program
function get_channel_program($channel_id){
  $channel_id = (isset($_POST['channel_id']) ? $_POST['channel_id'] : '');
  if (!is_numeric($channel_id)) :
    drupal_not_found();
  else :
    drupal_json_output($channel_id);
  endif;
}
```

file mudule.js :

```
Drupal.behaviors.ajaxProgram = {
        attach: function (context, settings) {

            // CSS Selector for the button which will trigger the AJAX call

            $('.channel-tv-tabs .tab .tabset .single-prog', context).click(function () {

                var channel_id = $(this).data('channel-id');

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/'+Drupal.settings.pathPrefix + 'ajax/channel/'+channel_id+'/get-program', // This is the AjAX URL set by the custom Module
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { channel_id : channel_id }, // Set the number of Li items requested
                    dataType: "json",          // Type of the content we're expecting in the response
                    success: function(data) {
                        var parsed_data = $.parseJSON(data);
                        console.log(parsed_data);  // Place AJAX content inside the ajax wrapper div
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                        console.log(errorThrown);
                    }

                });

            });

        }
    };
```

Pls help me and tell what i do wrong?
When I try go to link http://hostname/ru/ajax/channel/25/get-program I recive page not found

Comment: Not the issue, but why when $channel_id is automatically passed in do you grab it from POST again? Makes the data param in the ajax call redundant.

Comment: @J.Reynolds I grab it from POST for example

Comment: Yes but it is redundant as it is in the url as well. Either lose it in the url or in POST. Plus you are passing it over in post as an object.

Comment: @J.Reynolds, You say about `$channel_id = arg(2)` ?

Comment: No, this line does it automatically: 'page arguments' => array(2),. Then it is caught here: function get_channel_program($channel_id). And then you overwrite it just the next line by getting it from POST. And I will inspect that post value as i am sure it is an object in key  value pair.

Comment: @J.Reynolds, but i still recived 500 (Internal Server Error) from ajax

Comment: We can't know what the error is from here @ArtyomKondra, you need to check your server logs to get the real error message. Could be the fact the PHP is invalid, that should be fixed up first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the callback into this:

```
function get_channel_program($channel_id){
  if (!is_numeric($channel_id)) :
    drupal_not_found();
  else :
    drupal_json_output($channel_id);
  endif;
}
```

Change the jQuery into this:

```
$('.channel-tv-tabs .tab .tabset .single-prog', context).click(function () {
     ...
     $.get('/ajax/channel/'+channel_id+'/get-program', function(data) {
     alert("got "+ data);
   });
});
```

This uses HTTP [GET](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html) verb.

> According to the design of the HTTP specification, GET (along with
>   HEAD) requests are used only to read data and not change it

instead of POST

> The POST verb is most-often utilized to **create** new resources.